# What is the correct way to implement a table in Mongo object(document)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am kinda new to NoSQL databases and I want to implement the following type of object. I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose as ODM.

```
Field 1
Field 2
Table 1, where each row is:
    Column 1
    Column 2
    Column 3
```

In an SQL DB the table would be a separate, well, table, with first column being  key of the main object.

In Mongo I can see two ways to go. One is to make the following schema:

```
{
    Field1: Type,
    Field2: Type,
    Table1: [{
        Column1: Type,
        Column2: Type,
        Column3: Type
        }]
}
```

And the other is to make a separate collection "TableRow" and reference it, like that:

```
{
    Field1: Type,
    Field2: Type,
    Table1: [{
        Type: ObjectId,
        Ref: "TableRow"
        }]
}
```

Which one is better practice? Or is there an even better way that I've missed entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code

```
   {
    Field1: Type,
    Field2: Type,
    Table1: [{
    Column1: Type,
    Column2: Type,
    Column3: Type
    }]
   }
```